# Question about color filters for a liquid crystal display

Tags: electronic-filters

I'm not sure if 'engineering' is the right place to post this question. I'm studying how color filters for a liquid crystal display are fabricated. I found a table on the web which compares pros and cons of each pattern (Please take a look at the attached image).

[image: color filter patterns]

Questions:

- Why are the mosaic and delta patterns difficult to fabricate?
- Why is the driving circuit of the mosaic pattern complex?

Comment: Achieving a desired visual result with a mosaic pattern requires at least "rearranging" the red/green/blue data compared to how it is usually processed. That apparently can't be implemented with a simple circuit. Additionally, the circuit might perform a nontrivial algorithm that corrects for the unusual spatial arrangement of colors as per [subpixel rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering), although I suspect that that would happen before the circuit in question.

Comment: What's the source of the image, what does it say about the table? If it doesn't explain the table, then the contents of the table might be unreliable as well.

Comment: You might want to read up on the fabrication process of any of these variants. The one for the more "uniform" pattern (maybe even with long uninterrupted stripes) is likely more straightforward.

Comment: Possible source: http://qataoui.free.fr/What_is_TFT_LCD_TV_Monitor_Fabricating_TFT_LCD.htm